# is Angular 4 javascript framework?

Tags: javascript, angular

The problem is :
My friend told me that it is not JS framework. Is he right ? I've tried to collect evidences on the Internet to prove that it is a JS framework.

Comment: Your question can be directly answered by searching on the internet!

Comment: Collect evidence? I mean, what more do you need than look at the source or their website or...?

Comment: How about start from asking your friend *what is the definition of framework*, Then try to fit Angular in that definition. You can also check online, what a framework is and reconcile if you should actually listen to your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**.**AngularJS is a Javascript structural front-end framework for dynamic web apps**. It lets you use HTML as your template language and lets you extend HTML's syntax to express your application's components clearly and succinctly. Angular's data binding and dependency injection eliminate much of the code you would otherwise have to write.

Comment: Due to some researches online, someone told that Angular 4 is a typescript programming language and as I know typescript is superset of JS. So, maybe it typescript framework ? @jkjaikrishna

Comment: the ques is about angular4 not angularjs